# Netbeans Java Desktop Database application with login connecting to users from mysql

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I wanted to create a java desktop database application with the combination of the login window so that I will be able to display the user different types of options depending on their level assigned by mysql db. For example, some users may just have add rows privilege to specified tables and read on all others only. Is there any built in login swing window in netbeans?

Comment: Removed jdbc tag, because it is not related.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the default JDK, but there are third party libs that have them.  I have used SwingLabs Login Form before and it has worked nicely for me.